# Clearing a div if changed

Tags: jquery

I have the following code below and it shows the `resp` but if I delete the value from the input.  Is there a way that I can clear the class when the input is deleted?

**Code:**

```
{
    if (resp == '') {     }
    else {
        $(".error").text(resp);
    }
},
error: function (resp) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

**Invoke:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.postForm').on('blur', '#post_title', function (e) {

        $(".postForm #post_url_link").blur();
    });

    function postTitleCheck() {
        $(".postForm #post_title").blur();
    }
});
```

Comment: to clear use .empty() method for eg. $(".error").empty()

Comment: @SohilDesai Where though

Comment: how is this code invoked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if(!resp)
    {
     $(".error").text('');// here set blank if no response 

    }else{
        $(".error").text(resp);// here set response if it comes
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".error").empty();

if(resp != '')
    $(".error").text(resp);
```